# NavigationLink match any enum associated value

Tags: swiftui

How do I create a `NavigationLink` that matches any enum associated value?

I have this navigation enum for my app

```
enum NavRoute {
  case loggedOut
  case onboarding(OnboardingRoute)
   
  enum OnboardingRoute {
    case page1
    case page2
  }
}

@State var route = NavRoute.onboarding(.page1)
```

I want to write a `NavigationLink` like this

```
NavigationLink(
  tag: NavRoute.onboarding(any), // What do I put here??
  selection: $route
) {
  OnboardingView()
} label: {
  Text("Create account")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is how you suppose to use this: NavigationLink(tag:selection:destination:label:) are suppose to work when a binding *selection* are the same of *tag*, so not when this *case* have some associated value. Like the example bellow: (It automatically navigate to two because of .onAppear modifier.

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Navigation
//
//  Created by Allan Garcia on 04/11/22.
//

import SwiftUI

enum NavigationRouteTag {
    case one, two, three
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var route: NavigationRouteTag?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(
                    tag: .one,
                    selection: $route) {
                        Text("Hello World 1!")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Create Account 1!")
                    }
                NavigationLink(
                    tag: .two,
                    selection: $route) {
                        Text("Hello World 2!")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Create Account 2!")
                    }
                NavigationLink(
                    tag: .three,
                    selection: $route) {
                        Text("Hello World 3!")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Create Account 3!")
                    }
            }
            .onAppear {
                route = .two
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**PS: This API is also deprecated in iOS16, maybe a different approach will be better for you like .navigationDestination(for:destination:) modifier.**

Comment: They are the same type though. They are both `NavRoute` cases.

Comment: Yes, but the nested enum->enum don't work because wasn't designed to work like that. If you have data to pass use binding not in the route, or create two routes.